# Testing ExtJS application using selenium

Tags: selenium, extjs

Has anyone had success writing automated tests for ExtJS based web application? Lots of googling finds people with similar problems. If any one have have documents or link please share to my me

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Finding an element once the DOM is ready  would save you a lot of headache

```
public static boolean waitUntilDOMIsReady(WebDriver driver) {
    def maxSeconds = DEFAULT_WAIT_SECONDS * 10
    for (count in 1..maxSeconds) {
        Thread.sleep(100)
        def ready = isDOMReady(driver);
        if (ready) {
            break;
        }
    }
}

public static boolean isDOMReady(WebDriver driver){
    return driver.executeScript("return document.readyState");
}
```

After that it's just writing a normal selenium test